# Confusion with gRPC

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Platform: Windows 10 PC;
Java: 1.8.0_201;
gRPC: 1.21.x

I have recently looked into the Google RPC (gRPC) package to attempt to evaluate it for use with Java. I have read through a lot of the information available on the site (grpc.io) and have attempted to download/build/install it for test evaluation. **I have not had much luck.**

It's a little unclear (to me anyway) what exactly is needed in order to use gRPC. There seem to be a number of moving parts and it's hard to tell everything that is needed. I know that it uses Google Protobuf, so I followed directions to install the Protobuf compiler, `protoc`. I'm not sure if I need something else for Protobuf besides the compiler. I assume that there is a "core" to gRPC and then a language-specific module (e.g. for Java) that implements the necessary logic to interface with Java programs. I don't know if there are any other dependencies.

I am unable to clone the git repo due to security policies where I work, but I downloaded the distro (v1.21.x from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) and unpacked it into a directory. I followed the directions to build the sample client and server. The process failed due to missing files. Below is an excerpt of the failure.

```
> Task :grpc-compiler:compileJava_pluginExecutableJava_pluginCpp
java_generator.h
C:\Users\jo24447\workspace\gRPC\grpc-java-1.21.x\compiler\src\java_plugin\cpp\java_generator.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h': No such file or directory

java_plugin.cpp
c:\users\jo24447\workspace\grpc\grpc-java-1.21.x\compiler\src\java_plugin\cpp\java_generator.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h': No such file or directory

java_generator.cpp
c:\users\jo24447\workspace\grpc\grpc-java-1.21.x\compiler\src\java_plugin\cpp\java_generator.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h': No such file or directory
```

I joined the gRPC mailing list and submitted some questions describing the issues I'm having. The short reply indicated that I should pull down the latest version (which I have) - I had originally pulled down the master branch and apparently that was the wrong thing to do. It was implied that it came with a pre-built code generator plugin (codegen). I was not given a reason for the build failure.

A link to instructions to build the codegen plugin were also provided. The site documentation seems to indicate that I should not need to build the codegen unless I'm actually changing the code, which I am not. Regardless I looked through the instructions. It would appear that it is intended for this to done on a *nix platform. What are people who are doing this on a Windows platform supposed to do?

In any case, I attempted to do the build with the new distro and it fails with the same issue. I responded back and have heard nothing.

At this point I am stuck and have no idea what to do next.

Any ideas about the following would be very helpful and appreciated:

- The minimum required distributions to permit a successful build and
  subsequent usage
- Unambiguous directions on the steps needed to take
  it from downloaded distro(s) to fully functional application/utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have responded in part in what I assume is the [mailing list thread you referenced](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/grpc-io/_hA_rfi5fxU/discussion).

grpc-java is its own complete implementation. It is not based on "C core" at https://github.com/grpc/grpc.

In short, you have gotten off the beaten path; you should not need to compile grpc-java yourself. We have binaries already available on Maven Central.

When you downloaded grpc-java, you should have downloaded v1.12.0 which is the release tag, not v1.12.x. Released versions are easily downloaded in the [release section](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases).

We don't have unambiguous instructions when `git clone` is unavailable, because that is rare and the answers will vary for each environment.

Comment: If I interpret correctly, I don't need to download and do anything with grpc-java. I should just be able to set up my dependencies in my pom.xml and be done with it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Maven/Gradle will download the necessary components from Maven Central.

Comment: Now in retrospect, I don't know how I got so off track. Once I pulled down the correct distro (i.e. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases/tag/v1.20.0) - v1.20.0 **not** v.1.20.x, everything built/installed fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make changes to gRPC-Java or build it yourself see [the instructions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/COMPILING.md).
But you do not need to do this to use it.

---

To use in the Maven / Gradle project, just add the necessary dependencies:

Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle

```
compile 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.20.0'
compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.20.0'
compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.20.0'
```

---

For protobuf-based codegen, you can use plugins integrated with your build system:

[protobuf-maven-plugin](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/)

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.7.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.20.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

[protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.8'
  }
}

protobuf {
  protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.7.1"
  }
  plugins {
    grpc {
      artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.20.0'
    }
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
      grpc {}
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can find more details in [the README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md).